# Failed to adding Android Material Design Library in Gradle dependencies, I get this error

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

Each time I add the Android Material Design Library in Gradle dependencies, I get this error
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

When I add Multidex Support, I get

non-zero exit value 3

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myex.exam"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }

}

dependencies {
provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile files('src/main/libs/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar')
compile files('src/main/libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')

}
```

Comment: the folder seems odd. jdk1.8.0_20jdk to my mind the 2nd jdk is too much

Comment: I think you shouldn't use Java 1.8 to compile. 1.7 is the officially supported one.

Comment: Good point @azertiti, App Compiles but pushes out the support:appcompat library, AppCompatActivity is not resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Please add description